# Python - intentando entender programación orientada objetos

Tags: python, python-2.7

Cuando tengo una clase raiz o general y luego creo una clase nueva que herede de la primera y que trabaje con lo que esta puesto en la primera. ¿Cómo logro que la clase nueva reciba un parámetro al ejecutarse en el interior de mi clase general?

El resultado que esperaba obtener es algo como:

> numero1 numero1
>
> numero2

```
class general():
    def __init__ (self,dat):
    self.dat=dat
    self.funcion('numero1')

    print self.dat

class herencia(general):
    def funcion(self,parametro_para_funcion ):
    print 2*parametro_para _funcion


ejemplo=general('numero2')
```

Arroja el siguiente resultado:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>      File "ejemplo.py", line 16, in 
>        ejemplo=general('numero2')
>      File "ejemplo.py", line 5, in __init__
>         self.funcion('numero1')
>   AttributeError: general instance has no attribute 'funcion'

Comment: Una pregunta Shiki, ¿tu programa, tal como lo has escrito, funciona actualmente? Si no marca error, ¿qué resultado arroja? Edita tu pregunta siguiendo esta guía: [mcve]. Recuerda usar el botón `{}` para darle formato a tu código.

Comment: arroja el siguiente resultado:  traceback (most recent call last) file "ejemplo.py",line5, in __init__ self.funcion('numero') AtributeError:general instace has no atribute 'funcion' file "ejemplo.py", line 16 in <module> ejemplo=general('numero2')

Comment: @Shiki, por favor revisa el código que has puesto, comprobarás que no está correctamente indentado, y por tanto si alguien lo copia para tratar de ayudarte le dará errores de sintaxis. Corrígelo para facilitar el trabajo a quien te ayude.

Answer (score 1):

El error es bastante claro, la instancia del objeto general no tiene un atributo `funcion`, efectivamente la clase no tiene este atributo/método, la que si lo tiene es `herencia`. Es `herencia` la que hereda de `general` y no a la inversa.

esto sí debería funcionar:

```
h = herencia('numero2')
```